# Preserve scroll position on table when new row is added at the top

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Ive got a table with rows, the table wrapper has overflow:auto prop.

Im receiving new rows for the table via Web Socket, every time I do - the content Im currently on is being shifted to the bottom (the now row is being added at the top).

Any solution to lock the scroller?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const BetScroller = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([{ name: "Initial Name" }]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setData((prev) => [
        { name: `New Bet # ${Math.Floor(Math.random * 1000)}` },
        ...prev,
      ]);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={"Table"}>
      {data.map((bet) => (
        <div className={"Row"} key={bet.name}>
          {bet.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default BetScroller;
```

**Ive used setInterval to recreate the web socket**

--- CSS ---

```
.Table {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Row {
  border-bottom: 1px gray;
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Provide code for this. maybe you need to add fixed height to the table.

Comment: Just did and the table has fixed height